# Java Rectangular Selection

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I previously used rectangular selection mode on my Java project in eclipse, but after doing an Android project, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> now opens this box instead:

[image: Alt-Shift-A prompt]

How can I get the old behaviour back?

Comment: Remember when asking a question on Stack Overflow, you should ***actually ask a question***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a plugin messes with your keybindings, you can always go to:

> Window > Preferences > General > Keys

There, you can search for *Toggle Block Selection* (which is what I think you mean by "rectangular selection") and either assign a different key combination to it, or change it back to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and (if you want) assign a different combination to whatever had replaced it.

Comment: The toggle block selection binding is still ALT + SHIFT + A.
Do you have any idea why the three above appears?
If it is possible, i still want to use ALT + SHIFT + A for selection

Comment: Hmm, maybe try deleting the binding and then re-applying it? Eclipse should warn you of any conflicts, which should tell you what's overriding it. Alternatively, scroll through the commands (there are LOTS, though) and try to find the one clashing with yours.

Comment: ALT + SHIFT + A is only binded in the toggle block selection

The other three starts with ALT + SHIFT + A though

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks as though they're part of a combination, so just change that combination to start with something else... or unbind it altogether if you don't need it.